# XSLT 1.0 Move last 4 characters in a string to a new node

Tags: xslt-1.0

I have the following XML:

```
<Documents>
    <Form>
         <FormCode>HP 1000 01 20</FormCode>
    </Form>
    <Form>
         <FormCode>MS FULL 00 01 12 19</FormCode>
    </Form>
</Documents>
```

The desired output:

```
<Documents>
    <Form>
         <FormCode>HP 1000</FormCode>
         <FormDate>01 20</FormDate>
    </Form>
    <Form>
         <FormCode>MS FULL 00 01</FormCode>
         <FormDate>12 19</FormDate>
    </Form>
</Documents>
```

I need to extract the last 4 characters of `<FormCode>` and place them in a new node `<FormDate>`.  The length value of `<FormCode>` can vary for each form.  Any ideas of how to accomplish this with XSLT 1.0 would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Space is a character too. Your result extracts the last 5 characters, and removes 6 characters from the original.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

**XSLt 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Form">
    <xsl:variable name="len" select="string-length(FormCode)" />
    <xsl:copy>
        <FormCode>
            <xsl:value-of select="substring(FormCode, 1, $len - 6)" />
        </FormCode>
        <FormDate>
            <xsl:value-of select="substring(FormCode, $len - 4)" />
        </FormDate>
     </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```